# Loop issue in angular-ui-route when redirect to login

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome, angular-ui-router, chromium

We have two diferent apps in our environment, one that handles login and the main portal. When anyone try to access a portal url and its not logged, the "otherwise" function will save this url and redirect to login.

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise(function($injector, $location){

    console.log($location.absUrl());

    //save attempted url


    //redirect to login,
    var loginUrl=$location.absUrl() + '#/login';

    var $window=$injector.get('$window');
    console.log(loginUrl);
    $window.location.href=loginUrl;
});
```

This work fine in firefox, but in chrome, the 'login' state are never resolved, so it fall back to the default function every time, causing a loop.

You can see this issue in http://plnkr.co/edit/l51Wqn0EB1ySDjbScSvY

Could anyone help me with a solution?

EDIT : I need to perform the redirect with $window.location.href, because this app sometimes get loaded on /portal and need to redirect to /#/login.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the app initially loads, it is hitting the `""` path before going to the path in the URL (in your case, `#/login`).  Each time you do a `$window.location`, you tell the app to reload.  On each reload it looks for a state mapping to `""` and cannot find it so it hits the otherwise... thus looping.

You can handle the empty route with a "when"

```
.when('', '/login')
```

You can also default it to your home page, assuming you would have logic for your home page to kick the user back to login if they are not logged in.

Comment: Thanks man!. I know i shouldn't be using $window.location for redirect, and your other answer is the good practice on this issue, but for my particular case, this answer works.

Comment: Yeah, I left my other answer there for best practice.

Answer (score 0):

Not too sure if there is a need to use `$window.location`, but if you are only trying to store the current location and then direct to one of your states you can inject `$state` and use `$state.go(...)`

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise(function($injector, $location){

    console.log($location.absUrl());

    //save attempted url


    //redirect to login,
    var $state=$injector.get('$state');
    $state.go('login');
});
```

Updated plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/aMsjxQ9WQIXqrQ7e9MJq?p=preview

Comment: I forget to comment out that we need the $window.location.href redirect.